# Label above JSlider Thumb

Tags: java, swing, location, jlabel, jslider

i am trying to add a Label above the `JSlider` Thumb within the slider Component (coordinate-wise). Therefore I have tried to do the following in the Parent Component of the slider:

```
        this.setLayout(null);
        this.add(slider, 0);
        slider.setLocation(0, 0);
        JLabel label = new JLabel("test");
        label.setLocation(1000,0);
        label.setOpaque(false);
        this.setOpaque(false);
        this.add(label);
        revalidate();
        repaint();
```

Unfortunately the label is always visibly at x:0, y:0, but `label.getLocation()` returns x:1000, y:0 (the Parent Component is big enough for the given coordinates).

Does anybody know whats causing this or how i can fix it? Or maybe another suggestions to add a Labels above a `JSlider` Thumb?

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish? Do you want to show slider value while user moves the sliders knob?

Comment: nah, the content of the Label is static. I was trying to dynamically show a Label right above the Sliderthumb and had problems with adding the label to the panel properly since it is overlapping with another component and there for not opaque. I got it now, so its fine :)

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't use absolute Positions, use Layout Managers!

Try to use

```
this.setLayout(new GridLayout(2,0)); //The JFrame (or JPanel) is splitted right in two "chambers"
this.add(new JSlider());
this.add(new JTextField());
```

Comment: I think i asked the question inaccurately. I need the JLabel to be right above the JSlider-Thumb. Your solution is giving me a JLabel above the JSlider Component, or am I wrong?

Comment: Then just switch these two commands and write 
`this.add(new JTextField());
this.add(new JSlider());`

Comment: I guess there is still misunderstanding. The JLabel position should be dynamically changing with the JSlider value. And it should be right above the JSlider Thumb. Your solution gives me afaik a static JLabel field which is just above the JSlider Component.

Comment: then just make a object of the jtextfield and add the object; and make a Listener on the JSlider and everytime the value changes you change the position of the field

Comment: apparently GridLayout doesnt care about bounds/coordinates you set for a textfield